# Can I safely delete Desktop Sharing?

Tags: sharing

have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.  Can I safely  delete Desktop Sharing?  I am concerned that I might not get the updates I need from Ubuntu. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`Desktop Sharing` is in no way related to desktops. It's purpose is to allow remote login to your desktop if you chose so.

In fact , the updates and desktop sharing are related to two different programs.

For desktop sharing the program is called `vino`. You can safely remove it with running

```
sudo apt-get remove vino
```

in terminal.

Now if you want to ever use it, but don't want it to be enabled by default you can either disable it through <kbd>Startup Applications</kbd> or do

```
mv /etc/xdg/autostart/vino-server.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart/vino-server.desktop.bak
```

(which moves the actual file that calls `vino` to start on every GUI login, to a file with .bak extension , which won't be called on GUI login)

Comment: Thanks Serg. I actually have an application called Desktop Sharing. The preferences do not allow me to disable it.  If I use vino will this disable that application.  I understand sharing, but don't want this application. In the software center I can remove (uninstall) it.  That would be my choice if I don't screw up anything else. .... your thoughts.

Comment: @Karina Desktop Sharing is just generic name. The actual program that does the work is `vino`.   Do this  `awk '/Name/||/Exec/' /etc/xdg/autostart/vino-server.desktop` in terminal. The file has two fields - Name ( how program appears to the user ) and Exec (what actually runs). You will see that for the name it says "Desktop Sharing" but actual executable is `vino-server`

Comment: You're welcome. Let me know if you need any other help, and welcome to the askubuntu site !  :)